# ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file while start anaconda in Linux command line

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, anaconda, conda

While starting anaconda-navigator from linux command prompt
I got below error.
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file:

I am accessing Amazon instance(linux) EC2 from Amazon Cloud services.
I wanted to start Anaconda tool in that. I have installed Anaconda3 version.

As per documentation, I should use below command to start anaconda tool.

$ **anaconda-navigator**

But getting below Error.

**ERROR:**

**from PyQt5.QtGui import *
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

Software details:
(base) [ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-181 ~]$ conda --version
**conda 4.8.3**
(base) [ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-181 ~]$ python --version
**Python 3.7.3**

Tried below solutions, But none of them below helped to update the resolve or update the above library issue.

1. **conda install -c anaconda mesa-libgl-cos6-x86_64**
2. **sudo yum update
   sudo yum install libgl1-mesa-glx**
3. **conda remove anaconda-navigator
   conda install anaconda-navigator**
4. **conda update anaconda-navigator**

Could some help me to resolve this issue. I wanted to run anaconda software in linux server(amazon cloud server)

Comment: Don't you need a gpu-based instance for that?

Comment: This should give you the package you need to install: `yum whatprovides /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1`